# Question about Racemic Mixtures in Miller-Urey Experiment

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, chirality

I'm studying the Miller-Urey Experiment for my Biology class, and a significant point made by my professor was that Miller made a 50/50 racemic mixture of chiral monomers.

However, life is homochiral.

I'm trying to draw some significance out of Miller and Urey's experiment. Could life have started in multiple various places (because all you need for life to start is some organic molecules), so you could have developed various chiral forms of polymers (like amino acids), but one chiral form dominated and thus natural selection favoured that one form?

Thank you!